# how to context switch in a kernel module thread?

Tags: switch-statement, linux-device-driver

I'm wondering if there is a way for a kernel module thread to switch its current mm. Kernel threads usually use the last mm that was active before it was scheduled. Is it possible to switch to a particular mm in a kernel thread? 
I'm looking for a linux equivalent to `KeStackAttachProcess` in windows. 
`Context_switch()` and `switch_mm()` are not exported so I'm wondering what I can use to switch context in my kernel module thread.

Comment: Best way i have found so far based on all the googling is to sleep in process context(wait_* family of functions) in the kernel and wake up the thread when you want to do whatever you want to do in that context!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such function available currently to switch context. However, the same thing can be achieved in a different way. The best way i have found to do anything in the context of a particular process in the kernel, is to sleep in process context(wait_* family of functions) and wake up that thread and do whatever needs to be done in that context. This would ofcourse mean you would have to have the application call into the kernel via IOCTL or something and sleep on that thread and wake it up whenever you need to do something. This seems to be a very widely used and popular mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

old kernels dont have the kthread_ prefix
"kthread_use_mm - make the calling kthread operate on an address space"
"kthread_unuse_mm - reverse the effect of kthread_use_mm()"