# Is there a way to ensure that a kernel module runs in a specific process context?

Tags: process, linux-kernel, kernel-module

Basically, how can I make sure that in my module, a specific process is `current`. I've looked at `kick_process`, but I'm not sure how to have my module execute in the context of that process once kicking it into kernel mode.

I found this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24888548/how-to-context-switch-in-a-kernel-module-thread), but it has no replies. I believe an answer to my question could help that asker as well.

Note: I am aware that if I want the `task_struct` of a process, I can look it up. I'm interested in running in a specific context since I want to call functions that reference `current`.

Comment: The kernel doesn't tend to service processes by imposing on them from other contexts (other than scheduling itself and signal delivery), it is more usual for a process to request service from the kernel.  Perhaps you can share more about your ultimate goal? What functions referencing `current` do you want to call?

Comment: @caf not really a function from current, but I want to call kvm ioctls related to a qemu-kvm process. If there's no way to do this, I have some other ideas about achieving this, but i believe the most convenient would be to run in the context of qemu-kvm. I should note that for my application, I can't modify qemu-kvm.

Comment: I don't believe it's possible without adding some functionality to the core kernel (for example, a way to register a function to be called when a process is about to return to userspace).  You could do it from userspace using `ptrace()` (the same way `gdb` lets you run functions in the context of the process being debugged).

Comment: @caf: `ptrace()` sounds like a great idea. Don't know why I got so tunnel-visioned into doing everything in kernelspace. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Best way i have found to do anything in the context of a particular process in the kernel, is to sleep in process context(wait_* family of functions) and wake up that thread and do whatever needs to be done in that context. This would ofcourse mean you would have to have the application call into the kernel via IOCTL or something and sleep on that thread and wake it up whenever you need to do something. This seems to be a very widely used and popular mechanism.

Comment: Got it, thanks! I was looking for a way to do this without having to modify the existing application, though adding an ioctl certainly is a viable route.